# У меня есть сервер, но на новом телефоне не удается подключиться к Wi-Fi(он без доступа к сети)

Tags: java, android

возникла такая проблема. Мне нужно подключиться к роутеру к которому подключено по локальной сети оборудование, но телефон выбрасывает из сети, так как доступа к интрнету на роутере нет. С одного телефона подключается и весит в сети, а с другого нет. Как это можно исправить или прописать в коде программы?

Comment: На роутер можете зайти? Что за роутер? Может стоит ограничение по количеству клиентов,маку,IP. Причем тут код программы? И наличие интернета в Wi-Fi никак не зависит на то, будет телефон держаться за эту сеть или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Перезапусти роутер и свой телефон(смартфон). После этого зайди на настройки своего роутера и перезапусти DHCP сервер если он включен на автомат. Если у тебя все ИП вручную прописаны то проверь таблицу раздачи этих адресов(скорее всего у тебя вылетает из-за конфликта ИП).

Comment: С другого телефона все подключается, на роутере базовые настройки(то есть я ничего на нем не менял). Можно ли как-то на телефоне отключить проверку сети на наличие интернета?

Comment: Такой функции как " отключить на телефоне проверку сети на наличие интернета" не существует. Он _алогичен_. Проблема а) В твоем роутере, метод решение я написал выше. б) В твоем телефоне, можешь сделать _factory reset_ на своем телефоне и проверить как ведет себя твой смартфон в других сетях где отсутствует подключение к (прекрасному) WWW.

Answer (score 0):

Помогла смена ip на телефоне на статический.